# configure my PermissionCrudController to manipulate permissions in Backpack for Laravel PermissionManager

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Previously I created my `PermissionCrudController` (`App\Http\Controllers\Admin`) and in the `setup()` I could use the created permissions to allow access to the crud functions.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
  
use Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Controllers\PermissionCrudController as PermissionControllerPrincipal;

/**
 * Class PermissionCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class PermissionCrudController extends PermissionControllerPrincipal
{
    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        parent::setup();

        if (!backpack_user()->can('permiso_listar_admin')) {
            $this->crud->denyAccess('list'); //not working
        }

        $this->crud->denyAccess('create'); //not working
        $this->crud->denyAccess('update'); //not working
        $this->crud->denyAccess('delete'); //not working
    }

}
```

But currently it doesn't work anymore. What would be the correct or updated way to do it?

At the moment I only have to block access for everyone on
"`App\Config\Backpack\Permissionmanager.php`" the array:

```
'allow_permission_create' => false,
'allow_permission_update' => false,
'allow_permission_delete' => false,
'allow_role_create' => false,
'allow_role_update' => false,
'allow_role_delete' => false,
```

But the requirement is that some users can create roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you have done this already, but you need to tell the service container to use your controller instead of the original one:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            \Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Controllers\PermissionCrudController::class,
            \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PermissionCrudController::class
        );
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Let us know if this resolves the issue for you.

Cheers!

Comment: Incredible that I spent hours on this detail. In my previous projects I had the Users, Permissions and Roles container services assigned. For some reason here I only had it assigned for users, I was missing permissions and roles. Thank you. cheers